# st terminal: shrink of bottom bar because of font with small size

Tags: terminal, suckless-terminal

I'm using `proggycleanTT` font with size of 10, and with current 2k screen, it shrinked at bottom bar, there's redundant space bar at bottom of screen, especially when I use vim or tmux I can see it clearly.

How can I get rid of redundant space bar?

EDIT: I tried to use `xdotool` to resize manually, the size of terminal change but it couldn't precisely at the bottom, the size is `2560x1442`.

I don't understand why X can't recognize the size of my monitor, what should be done for X to resize to 2560x1400 that include the font even the size of font.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the program can either divide the screen-width into an even number of cells, ***or*** the screen-height, but (except for special cases), not both.  TrueType fonts don't change the *aspect ratio* of the character cells.

Comment: Yes, it's TrueType font, I can have other softwares run in fullscreen and they're in full without bottom bar like firefox and chrome. If it depends on some factors that you mentioned, how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Some applications adjust the whitespace around their data to fill it in nicely.  Others do not.  To make **`st`** do this, you will have to modify the program.

Comment: I can read the `st` `xst` sourcecode to adjust `config.h` but can't do a path, not enough knowledge about `c` to do this. Any materials that you can suggest to solve this issue?